# How to dynamically add an Id to the navbar used on laravel/VueJs SPA

Tags: php, css, laravel, vue.js

On my laravel/vuejs Single Page App, i am mounting all my components on a single page (welcome.blade.php file), and inside i have included my navbar blade component @include('layouts.navbar').

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    @include('layouts.homenavbar')
    <router-view></router-view>
@endsection
```

My homepage has a transparent background navbar on a huge banner. However, the same navbar is served to the other pages/components but with a coloured background and white colored fonts. I tried using itenary to check if the incoming route is home and add an id that gives the navbar a transparent background, and if the route isn't home leave the coloured background navbar like so;

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" id=>"{{ Route::currentRouteName() === 'home' ? "home_nav" : ''}}">
----
</nav>
```

and in my css;

```
#home_nav{
  background: iceblue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

However, when i go to other routes i keep getting a transparent navbar unless i reload the page.
How do i fix this?

Comment: i would prefer directly using style="{{ Route::currentRouteName() === 'home' ? 'background: iceblue; color: #fff;' : '' }}"

Comment: Thanks @Vernon..its the same, it doesn't work until i do a page reload.

Comment: is your redirect happen in Vue JS? If yes, you might need to use window.location.href

Comment: My routing and all works very fine. My navbar is on blade. But the adding of the Id dynamically is not just happening unless the page is reloaded

Comment: Yes, ID can only be change when the page reload. Because PHP is not in virtual DOM like Vue JS where it will refresh the page when there is changes.

Comment: OK @vernon .so there's probably no way I could  change the id of the navabar dynamically then?

Comment: when you redirect to other page, instead of using vue-router, you can redirect using window.location.href = '/other-page'. Then the page will be reloaded

Comment: The objective of making a SPA will then be defeated if I follow that route..many thanks for your help anyways

Comment: Yes, except you code everything in Vue JS

Answer (score 0):

Try checking window.location.href to get current route on mounted() state of your routes and add the css on that condition

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a **class** as a **prop** with the route:

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Comment: pls can u explain more?I haven't fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the most simple solution. put the route name on the surrounding div and target it with css. e.g.

```
.home .navbar {}
.about .navbar {}
```

Or as you are using router view you can get the current route path in your nav bar component and use this to create a computed property to return the class you need.

```
<nav :class="['some','class', backgroundColor]"></nav>

...
computed: {
    backgroundColor() {
        switch (this.$route.fullPath) {
            case ('/'):
                return 'bg-blue';

            case ('/about'):
                return 'bg-pink';

            default:
                return 'bg-red';

        }
    }
},
```